# Homogeneous equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following homogeneous equation:

Thanks for your tips

$xy^3y′=2(y^4+x^4)$

> I think this isHomogeneous of order4

=> $xy^3dy/dx=2(y^4+x^4/1)$

=> $xy^3dy=2(x^4+y^4)dx$

=> $xy^3dy-2(x^4+y^4)dx=0$

I do not know how to continued

Comment: [Hmmmm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_differential_equation)...

Comment: The Ansatz $y(x)=x\cdot f(x)$, which is natural as factors out and lets you cancel the $x^4$-term, gives you something simpler: $x\cdot f'(x)=f(x)+2f(x)^{-3}$. Wolfram Alpha even sovles it: $f(x)=(c x^4-2)^\frac{1}{4}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the substitution $v=y^4$. Then by the chain rule we have $v'=4y^3 y'$. Now your DE turns into:
$$x \frac{v'}{4}=2(v+x^4)$$
Then can be simplified to:
$$v'-8\frac{v}{x}=8x^3$$
We first solve the homogeneous part:
$$v_h' -8\frac{v_h}{x}=0$$
This leads to $v_h=c\cdot x^8$ so that $v_h'=c\cdot 8x^7$. This is our homogeneous solution. Now to find a particular solution we guess it will look something like $$v_p=ax^4+bx^3+dx^2+3x+f$$
Filling this into the DE we get:
$$(4ax^3 +3bx^2+2dx+3)-\frac{8}{x}(ax^4+bx^3+dx^2+3x+f)=8x^3$$
the only terms with $x^3$ in it are the $4ax^3$ and the $-8ax^3$. Conclusion: $-4a=8$ so $a=-2$. All the other terms are zero. We now have our particular solution $v_p=-2x^4$. The general solution is the sum of the particular and homogeneous solution so
$$v_g=c\cdot x^8 -2x^4$$
Now backsubstitute $v=y^4$ or $y=v^{\frac{1}{4}}$ to obtain the final answer.

Comment: Do you mean that:I "changed the variable" And then I continue??

Comment: Yeah when I say 'make the substitution' in the beginning this is basically just a change of variable.

Comment: Yes you change it into a DE for $v$ where $v=y^4$ like I did above and then you solve this simpler DE for $v$. Then you can easily find $y$ by using $y=v^{\frac{1}{4}}$.

Comment: Always glad to help! I like solving DE's, they're like little puzzles.